# NullPointerException when use DatabaseHelper second times

Tags: android, sqlite, getwritabledatabase

I want to update data and show in the fragment list, the data is already pass into db, but it got NullPointerException when use getWritableDatabase() to update,

Now I know it can't called getWritableDatabase() and getReadableDatabase() again, and no need to close database.

How should I do to finish it?

Calculator

```
    public class CalcFragment extends Fragment {

    OnEqualSelectedListener mCallback;

    public interface OnEqualSelectedListener {

        public void updateResult();
    }
    ...
    private void getEqualResult() {

        textview_result.setText(mResult + sum);

        mDbHelper = new DB(getActivity());
        mDbHelper.open();
        mDbHelper.create(mResult + sum);
        mDbHelper.close();

        mCallback.updateResult();
...
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements CalcFragment.OnEqualSelectedListener {

    View view;
    ...
    @Override
    public void updateResult() {
        NoteFragment fragmentResult = new NoteFragment();
        fragmentResult.updateView();
        if(Debug.log){ Log.d("MainActivity", "updateResult");}
    }
```

DB.class

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    ...

    public DB(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;

    if (Debug.log) {
        Log.d("DB", "DB");
    }

}

public DB open() throws SQLException {

        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if (Debug.log) {Log.d("DB", "SQLException");
    }
    return this;
}

public void close() {

    dbHelper.close();
    if (Debug.log) {
        Log.d("DB", "close");
    }

}

public Cursor getAll() {
    mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM history ORDER BY created DESC",
            null);

    return mCursor;
}
```

List Note

```
public class NoteFragment extends ListFragment {


private DB mDbHelper;
private Cursor mCursor;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    ...

public void setAdapter(){

    mDbHelper = new DB(getActivity());
    mDbHelper.open();
    mCursor = mDbHelper.getAll();
    getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor);

    String[] from_column = new String[]{DB.KEY_ITEM, DB.KEY_CREATED};
    int[] to_layout = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            mCursor, from_column, to_layout);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    if(Debug.log){ Log.d("NoteFragment", "setAdapter");}

}

public void updateView(){

    mDbHelper = new DB(getActivity());
    mDbHelper.open();
    mCursor = mDbHelper.getAll();
    getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor);

    String[] from_column = new String[]{DB.KEY_ITEM, DB.KEY_CREATED};
    int[] to_layout = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            mCursor, from_column, to_layout);

    adapter.changeCursor(mCursor);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if(Debug.log){ Log.d("NoteFragment", "updateView");}
}
```

log

```
03-27 06:09:05.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 06:09:05.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2652): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-27 06:09:05.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2652):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
03-27 06:09:05.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2652):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
03-27 06:09:05.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2652):     at com.example.mycalc.DB.open(DB.java:85)
03-27 06:09:05.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2652):     at com.example.mycalc.NoteFragment.updateView(NoteFragment.java:85)
03-27 06:09:05.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2652):     at com.example.mycalc.MainActivity.updateResult(MainActivity.java:34)
03-27 06:09:05.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2652):     at com.example.mycalc.CalcFragment.getEqualResult(CalcFragment.java:258)
03-27 06:09:05.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2652):     at com.example.mycalc.CalcFragment.access$1(CalcFragment.java:239)
03-27 06:09:05.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2652):     at com.example.mycalc.CalcFragment$1.onClick(CalcFragment.java:171)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getActivity()` `Context` passed to the sqlite helper was `null`. This is because you've just created the fragment with `new` in `updateResult()` and it's not attached to any activity yet.

Generally, you should not be invoking methods such as your `updateView()` on fragments directly like this. Instead, wait for the fragment lifecycle callbacks such as `onCreateView()` to be invoked by the framework.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I use FragmentTransaction to replace the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `fragmentResult.updateView();` add/replace your fragment in activity.

Only after fragment is attached to the activity you can have context from `getActivity()` inside fragment.